# Iframe anchor link in src jumping

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an **iframe in the middle of a page**.
I am trying to display another page within the iframe, but to start it a couple of paragraphs down, not at the top.

So I have put an anchor into my iframe src, corresponding to an anchor name tag in my other page.

The iframe scrolls itself ok, but the main body of the page also scrolls so that the top of the iframe is at the top of the screen, which is not what I intended.

Is there a way to scroll just the iframe, with the **top of the main page still at the top of the screen**?

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.mysite.com/#anchorlink"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can temporary set main page's body style position to "fixed" and then reset it to default in iframe "onload" event, e.g. give your iframe an ID

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id = "ifr"></iframe>
```

and add following code:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById("ifr");

document.body.style.position = "fixed";

ifr.onload = function() {document.body.style.position = ""};
ifr.src =  "http://www.mysite.com/#anchorlink"
```

Answer (score 0):

put your iframe within table tag and give iframe required height so it can also avoid scroll if not required

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>top section</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><iframe frameborder="0" height='650px;' width='100%'
                    id="pageframe" name="pageframe" src="http://www.mysite.com/#anchorlink"> </iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bottom section</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: ok...I might not understand your problem well enough...better you put fiddle so everyone can easily understand your problem